# python two list merge into one list with tuple

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to merge two lists into list(tuple()) here's example

```
['robin', 'kate', 'shim', 'help'] # this was originally dictionary keys
```

with:

```
[100, 200, 300, 400, 500] # this was originally dictionary values
```

into:

```
[('robin', 100), ('kate', 200), ...]
```

I need some solutions please help me

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to cast the output of `dict.items()` into a `list`, i.e. `list(dict.items())`.

Comment: The simplest is from a dictionary as the previous comment mentions. But, if you have names and scores separately you can use: ` [(name, score) for name, score in zip(names, scores)]` to generate the desired list of tuples.

Comment: @DarrylG or just `list(zip(names, scores))` to follow the easiest to write version as noted through the linked thread.

Comment: @metatoaster--good point on  just `list(zip(names, scores))`